# QML Scroll View does not allow scrolling of its content

Tags: qt, qml

I need to create components dynamically add added to an area of the screen that, of course, needs to be scrollable. I found out that no matter how many of components I added with the scroll bar as its parent, the scroll bars would not appear and the element would not be scrollable.

I did a little fiddling and I think I came up with a minum working example of what I am talking about:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ScrollView {
        width: 200
        height: 200
        clip: true

        Label {
            text: "ABC"
            font.pixelSize: 224
        }

//        Rectangle {
//            color: "#ff0000"
//            width: 100
//            height: 100
//        }

    }
}
```

This is a modified version of the example used int he official documentation. However when I uncomment the square the screen is no longer scrollable (scroll bars never appear).

If I remove the label and leave the rectangle (making it larger so that there is something to scroll to) it still doesn't work.

I am using Qt 5.10.

Comment: Have you found some solution to this issue? I am with Qt 5.12 and the behaviour I am facing is pretty much the same

Comment: I have actually. I post it as solution so I can add the code.

Answer (score 0):

So the code below worked for me. I defined a rectangle as a backgroud to get border lines to a scrollable table that I need to create.

```
Rectangle {
    id: tableBackground
    color: "#ffffff"
    border.width: 2
    border.color: "#EDEDEE"
    radius: 4
    anchors.top: tableHeader.bottom
    anchors.left: tableHeader.left
    width: vmTableWidth
    height: vmTableHeight - tableHeader.height

    ScrollView {
        id: tableArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        clip: true
        ListView {
            id: patientListView
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: patientList
            delegate: VMPatientEntry {
                onFetchReport: {
                   // This is a signal emitted by my VMPatientEntry.
                }
            }
            onCurrentIndexChanged: {
                 // Do stuff when the current index changes.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I hope this answer allows someone to fix their problem as well.

Comment: What specifically was the problem and solution?  Was adding anchors.fill to the scrollview the solution?